# Can i use relationship collection returned by a match query to be used as a input set in another query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example I want to find all the relationships that start from station A
and end at station B. 
I know passing node result list as input works perfectly,
but something like below does not gives me correct result, as it ignores the parameter r returned by first query

```
MATCH (from:TrainStation { stationCode:'A' })-[r]->()
with  r
MATCH ()-[r]->(to:TrainStation {stationCode:'B'})
return distinct r
```

Comment: Hi, Check this one,

MATCH (from:TrainStation { stationCode:'A' })-[r:relation_name]->(n)
with  r,from 
OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[r]->(from{stationCode:'B'})with  r
return {relation:[{r:collect(distinct r)}]}

Comment: Sorry for late reply
This works for me too

Thanks for the asnwer

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work if your database actually has the appropriate data.

However, there is no need to perform such a roundabout query when you can simply do this:

```
MATCH (from:TrainStation {stationCode:'A'})-[r]->(to:TrainStation {stationCode:'B'})
RETURN r;
```

If the above query also returns no result, then that shgows clearly that your DB does not have the appropriate data.